# Open Data/Image To Another View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to find out how to open an item (example: an image) from one view to another.

Basically user taps on a button that I customize into a picture. It will then bring the user to another view with that picture on the view.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the view controller and make a new init method:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil image:(UIImage*)image
    self = [super initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
       [imageView setImage:image]
    }
    return self;
}
```

imageView is an outlet to a UIImageView in the nib

You can replace the initWithNibName with init if it suits you.

EDIT: Based on your comments you need to pass a reference to the view controller with the image.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil delegate:(id)delegate
    self = [super initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
       viewDelegate = delegate; // you can use this to reference the view with the image
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: If I have say... 5 views. The 5th view is where all the images go to. 4 of those other views are just normal windows with texts, images, and etc. How can I link all those 4 views to the 5th view?

Comment: Awesome.. I'll try this out. Thank you for the help. I'll report back if I have more question =]

Comment: If the answer is correct please remember to mark it. If it's not exactly what you are looking for but helps, vote it up.  People on Stackoverflow will be more willing to help you if you do this for every question you have.

Comment: I'm trying to get this correctly. I will be putting this code in the 5th view, correct? Which is where the images are going to...